# Android - BitmapFactory treats all images as landscape

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I want to load image bytes into ImageView using BitmapFactory with this code:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length));
```

It works, but every image shown is landscaped. Same thing is when I try to load image from URL with BitmapFactory. Picasso does very well when loading image from URL, but in this case I need to load image bytes into ImageView.

Moreover, when I read image from URL with BitampFactory and print dimensions they are same both for portrait and landscape images.

For example, portrait image is 720x1280 and landscape is 1280x720 and it will print 1280x720 for both as it treats all images like they are landscape!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this image coming from that it's a byte array? Also is the image by default a landscape or portrait image?

Comment: You should read the orientation from the jpg file. Use ExifInterface. And rotate bitmap when needed.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp image is coming from the phone, sent over REST to Heroku Postgres database and then retrieved, but I think that does not matter because this is also the case when I load images in ImageView directly from phone.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks, I did it already, but I sent image bytes over the REST, so can I do the same when it is retrieved or there are only raw bytes with no additional information about bitmap?

Comment: Are you receiving a jpg file? Did you put those jpg bytes in that byte array? If yes than you have all info. And you have a Samsung phone. They are known to have this nasty habit.

Comment: @blackapps I used Bitmap compress function to get bytes from jpg image, so will I have all information?

Comment: No. A bitmap does not contain orientation info. And no exif header. So if you compress it to a jpg the jpg will also not contain orientation information nor an ecif header.

Comment: Ehhh... `I used Bitmap compress function to get bytes from jpg image` That is impossible. If you use compress then you produce the bytes for a jpg file. If you get a bitmap from a jpg then you used one of the decode functions of BitmapFactory. Its time you realize and tell what you are doing.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyway, I think only solution will be to read orientation with ExifInterface and put it in JSON along with bytes? But I am wondering why this was not discussed before if that is common problem with BitmapFactory and not specifically with phone because on Android Studio emulator and Samsung phone  is the same situation.